# Paused animation finishes when an app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I have a view that im moving using this

```
func r() {
    movel.constant = self.view.bounds.width - self.move.bounds.width
    move.setNeedsLayout()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: time, delay: 0, options:[], animations: {
        self.move.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
            if (finished == true){
                self.timerand()
                self.l()
            }else{
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
    })
}
```

And I'm using these functions to pause and resume it

```
func movestop() {
    pausedmovetime = self.move.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
    self.move.layer.speed = 0.0
    self.move.layer.timeOffset = pausedmovetime
}

func movestart() {
    self.move.layer.speed = 1.0
    self.move.layer.timeOffset = 0.0
    self.move.layer.beginTime = 0.0
    let timeSincePause = self.move.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedmovetime
    self.move.layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
}
```

The app works fine but when I go out of the app I call the `movestop()` but when I come back it is at its final position and the completion block doesnt get called

Comment: Completion block should call but that case you will get`finished == false` Try that actually i am not 100 % sure on this part

Comment: you can increase delay and try

Comment: okay i tried it now starts from the begining but why is it even in the completion block why isnt it paused

Comment: @WajdiMuhtadi Did you try what i said

Comment: yes i did it now calls the functions but i want it to resume